# Image Resize on Mobile

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get the images on my small page working right on mobile. Right now they do not resize at all.  I've already also tried to search around on here to find an answer before posting this, but none of the solutions I've found worked for me.

The URL of the site is at: [crypto.mmo-spellbook.com/app/](http://crypto.mmo-spellbook.com/app/)

I simply want the menu bar with the icons to resize on mobile. I've tried to use bootstrap and add the `img-responsive` tag but that didn't work (so I removed it), I've also tried to add a div around the menu with a 100% width but that didn't help either. I do have the max-width set as well:

```
img {
    height: auto !important;
    max-width: 100% !important;
}
```

In my header I so also have:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, height=device-height, user-scalable=0">
```

Which makes the iframe resize properly, but not the actual images. The page is very simple, but it seems the images just don't want to resize.

Help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use flex and update your CSS like this :

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #353c48;
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

remove all the styles from the `li` (no float needed)

And if you want to center the elements add this CSS :

```
li:first-child {
   margin-left:auto;
}
li:last-child {
   margin-right:auto;
}
```

Full code :

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #353c48;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

ul li img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

ul li:first-child {
  margin-left: auto;
}

ul li:last-child {
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="coinpot-menu">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="https://coinpot.co" target="faucetframe"><img src="http://crypto.mmo-spellbook.com/app/images/coinpot.png"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="http://moonbit.co.in/?ref=9abae445ca39" target="faucetframe"><img src="http://crypto.mmo-spellbook.com/app/images/moonbitcoin.png"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="http://moonliteco.in/?ref=2f13109a9e5f" target="faucetframe"><img src="http://crypto.mmo-spellbook.com/app/images/moonlitecoin.png"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="http://moondoge.co.in/?ref=02dfddfecb26" target="faucetframe"><img src="http://crypto.mmo-spellbook.com/app/images/moondogecoin.png"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="http://moondash.co.in/?ref=5E3DE726BCCB" target="faucetframe"><img src="http://crypto.mmo-spellbook.com/app/images/moondashcoin.png"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="http://bonusbitcoin.co/?ref=CD8C7FD96B63" target="faucetframe"><img src="http://crypto.mmo-spellbook.com/app/images/bonusbitcoin.png"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="http://bitfun.co/?ref=86E32F2DCAFA" target="faucetframe"><img src="http://crypto.mmo-spellbook.com/app/images/bitfun.png"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="http://crypto.mmo-spellbook.com/app/help.html" target="faucetframe"><img src="http://crypto.mmo-spellbook.com/app/images/questionmark.png" height="100%" width="100%"></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: That worked, thank you so much! You're a life saver!

Comment: @DJYumene you're welcome ;) i also update the answer with code if you want to have the images centred